# Is there such a thing as a shared reference count smart pointer?

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers, raii, reference-counting

Programmers using `boost::shared_ptr` need to avoid cycles so that a resource leak is not created. The general advice is to use a `boost::weak_ptr` in the cases where such a cycle might be created. However doing so creates a gap in intention where one might have preferred to use a `shared_ptr` but didn't do so only because of the cycle problem.

It seems to me, though, that it should be possible to create a special kind of shared_ptr which avoids the cycle problem by linking the reference count of all the pointers in the cycle. And since I can think of a way to do it, I'm wondering does such a thing exists.

For the sake of proving that I'm not crazy, or perhaps that I am, I offer the following poorly thought out and ugly proof of concept:

```
#define BOOST_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATE_FRIENDS

#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct shared_count_ptr
{
    boost::shared_ptr<T> innerPtr;
    template <typename TT>
    void link( boost::shared_ptr<T> & sharedPtr, boost::shared_ptr<TT> & linked )
    {
        innerPtr    = sharedPtr;
        innerPtr.pn = linked.pn;
    }
};

struct Hand;
struct Arm
{
    Arm()  { std::cout << "Creating Arm\n";   }
    ~Arm() { std::cout << "Destroying Arm\n"; }

    shared_count_ptr<Hand> hand;
};

struct Hand
{
    Hand()  { std::cout << "Creating Hand\n";   }
    ~Hand() { std::cout << "Destroying Hand\n"; }

    shared_count_ptr<Arm> arm;
};

int main()
{
    boost::shared_ptr<Arm> savedArm;

    std::cout << "Scope 0 entered\n";
    {
        std::cout << "\tScope 1 entered\n" ;

        boost::shared_ptr<Arm> arm( new Arm );
        {
            std::cout << "\t\tScope 2 entered\n";
            boost::shared_ptr<Hand>  hand( new Hand );

            hand->arm.link( arm, arm->hand );
            arm->hand.innerPtr = hand;

            savedArm = arm;
        }
        std::cout << "\t\tScope 2 exited\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\tScope 1 exited\n";
    std::cout << "\tScope 0 about to exit\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The general concept being that in the eyes of the imaginary `shared_count_ptr`, the Arm and Hand are the effectively same object.

So:

- **Does such a think already exist in `boost`?**
- **If not, is it because it's a terrible idea?** (Or did I just come up with something clever?)

Comment: I can't imagine a need for this that couldn't rather easily be avoided by making some small changes. I think the main problem is that sometimes (or quite often) you might not want the pointers to be created at the same time, this could make it a lot more complicated. Or forcing programmers to explicitly link pointers is just asking for trouble. Do note that your shared_count_ptr class should probably not have a shared_ptr member, since it already inherits off of it, unless I misunderstand your design.

Comment: The inheritance was left over from is-a and going to has-a. Fixed. I'm sure there's a much better way to implement this that would be much less ugly.

Comment: i guess if your algorithm uses linked lists instead of a simple shared int counter, you could detect cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple test. Create a complete graph on 17 vertices, such that the program points only to vertex 0. Start removing edges at random. Does your idea work? (Spoiler: it doesn't).

Comment: I.e. there's no matching `unlink`, nor is it feasible to write one.

Comment: Perhaps not for my straw man example, but I believe it would for a more well thought out implementation.

Comment: You are welcome to try and come up with one. I will not hold my breath.

Comment: You may be correct. I'm not in the position to spend any significant amount of time on more investigation. My personal use case however was in a static relationship, and so removing the linked relationship was not important.

Comment: No reference-counting scheme can possibly detect cycles on its own, without at least some input from the programmer. If you are willing to provide such input, sure, it's possible. Make a smart pointer with a runtime-selectable policy (select between strong and weak kinds). This is more or less equivalent to what you have, but the interface is simpler.

Comment: I think we may be talking about the same concept then. The intention here is to encode the a priori knowledge into the smart pointers about which would otherwise be a cycle. Certainly my 2am straw-man example is flawed, but the question is about the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine you *could* do something along those lines. However, in such a structure every pointer `A` needs to be aware about every single other pointer `B`, such that either `B` can be reached from `A` or vice versa. I don't see how this can possibly scale to more than a tiny number of interconnected pointers.

It would seem that if you want to support circular references without any help from the programmer, you more or less need a full-blown garbage collector rather than a simple reference counting scheme (I'd love to be proved wrong on this).

Comment: The general concept (which may not be well represented by my example) is that you should be able to separate the idea of reference count and type being pointed to. Conceptually it should scale as well as any proliferation of smart_pointers to the same object. Cycle *detection* would certainly need full-blown garbage collection. What I'm suggesting is that if the author is aware of the cycle to begin with, it should be possible to use that knowledge to avoid the problem.